# SQL parameters with LIKE ?% force use index

Tags: sql, indexing, parameters, h2, sql-like

How can i force to use index when i use LIKE (maybe a better solution?) with parameter binding when i just want to search with wildcard after the word like foo%? See this Examples with and without parameter binding. I want to prevent the tableScan in the parameter example.

Im using SpringBoot application with H2 database.

Query without parameters:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT resource_id FROM SEARCH_TABLE_874 WHERE word LIKE 'su%')
 GROUP BY resource_id ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC LIMIT 100
```

Execution Plan:

```
SELECT
    _1.RESOURCE_ID
FROM (
    SELECT
        RESOURCE_ID
    FROM PUBLIC.SEARCH_TABLE_874
    WHERE WORD LIKE 'su%'
) _1
    /* SELECT
        RESOURCE_ID
    FROM PUBLIC.SEARCH_TABLE_874
        /++ PUBLIC.IDX_SEARCH_TABLE_874_WORD: WORD >= 'su'
            AND WORD < 'sv'
         ++/
    WHERE WORD LIKE 'su%'
     */
GROUP BY RESOURCE_ID
ORDER BY =COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 100`
```

Query with parameters:

```
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT resource_id FROM SEARCH_TABLE_874 WHERE word LIKE :param) GROUP BY resource_id ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC LIMIT 100`
```

Execution Plan:

```
`SELECT
    _10.RESOURCE_ID
FROM (
    SELECT
        RESOURCE_ID
    FROM PUBLIC.SEARCH_TABLE_874
    WHERE WORD LIKE CONCAT(?1, '%')
) _10
    /* SELECT
        RESOURCE_ID
    FROM PUBLIC.SEARCH_TABLE_874
        /++ PUBLIC.SEARCH_TABLE_874.tableScan ++/
    WHERE WORD LIKE CONCAT(?1, '%')
     */
GROUP BY RESOURCE_ID
ORDER BY =COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

More details where the Query came from:

This is for a search engine.

The Query is generated to a String by the code as a String and then executed like:

```
Query query = session.createNativeQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("param", "foo%");
query.getFirstResult()
```

For the execution plan i wrote EXPLAIN in front of the Query. The structure is cause there can by many sub selects with UNION.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: I use no dbms. Please look at my edit at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in the execution plan of the query without parameters. I use now `WORD >= 'foo' AND WORD < 'fop'` instead of `LIKE 'foo%`. So the database can use the index.